# Using Lines and Planes to Separate and Isolate Parts of $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The planes $x+y+z=1$ and $x+y=z$ cut $\Bbb R^3$ into four parts. Find out whether the points $(1,-2,-3)$ and $(1,1,1)$ lie in the same part.

How can one do this without cheating? Can you give me hints?

Comment: @Rahul  Sorry, I meant x+y+z=0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the plane $x+y+z=1$ divides the space into two parts: those for which $x+y+z>1$ and those for which $x+y+z<1$. Which inequality holds for each point?

Comment: I meant x+y+z=0. But, they both hold for the same inequation.

Comment: You might want to double-check that; 1+(-2)+(-3)=-4 and 1+1+1=3, which are decidedly on different sides of the inequality, regardless of whether you have x+y+z=1 or x+y+z=0.

Comment: Oh boy! I must need some sleep. It is true. So, this is how you would proceed? Is there no other way of doing this? Any way to make this harder? ;)

Comment: This is probably the easiest way; if you want to, like, really prove it, you could note that $x+y+z$ is a continuous function of vectors and apply the intermediate value theorem to show that any path between the vectors eventually hits the plane.